Why was my post closed when I gave clear reasons that did not conflict wtih question posting guidelines?
I recently created the following post.  It was a split of an earlier post.  Someone asked if it was a duplicate and I explained in the comment that it is a split of a previous post because that post contained two different questions.  Recommendations from MSE about asking question in any post is that the poster should stick to only one question or one issue and that the different posts can be linked.  After I created the first post, the person who answered told me one of the questions can be found amongst an answer I posted earlier.  I am having the impression that the mods are not consistent in their expectations for community members to stick to site guidelines.

As far as I can tell, no moderator had anything to do with either of the linked posts.  The closed post was closed by a vote of community members (one who happens to have a gold tag badge, and can dupe close with a single vote).  These are curation activities, not moderator activities.

As to consistency, every person on this platform with sufficient reputation is given a voice.  They can vote (up or down), vote to close or reopen, and vote to delete or undelete.  Consistency is hard to manage when everyone gets to act according to their own beliefs and values.  The hope is that, in the long run, the wisdom of the crowds prevails.

@XanderHenderson I am not so petty as fault people for how they cast their votes. I am just wondering if rules are consistently applied. I have seen many questions with solution/proof verification tags where the person posting simply list their solutions and ask if what they have done is correct and the community is fine with it and people respond in their answer with length commentary and suggestions.

You're missing Xander's point, Seth. The rules are not applied by a deterministic Turing machine, but by a large number of individuals who have different beliefs and values. How a question fares can depend on just which users happen to see it.

@GerryMyerson I think a good synonym for what you are describing is a large numb er of individuals are capricious.

The "capricious" interpretation is one way to frame community moderation operations, and I sometimes view specific outcomes that way.  However in general I believe almost everyone here is doing that work in good faith.  In any case if the desire is to have your more narrowly focused post reopened, then a good way to try is by succinctly stating your case in the canonical thread here for requesting reopens, etc.

370 questions and zero answers?

@WillJagy what does "zero answers" mean?

from your profile page on Main, you have 370 questions, then for answers it says you have answered no questions. They tell me not to push people too hard to answer questions if they don't want to do that. At the same time, looking carefully at the questions of other people can show you what  seems to get good responses and what tends to get closed. My own reasons for voting to close questions are not the majority view, I mostly want the student to give the exact source of the problem and demonstrate knowledge of what the words mean.

@WillJagy I don't take issues with my post not getting answers.  I am simply pointing out how judgements are applied to why are post should be closed or not are not always strictly in accordance with MSE site written and documented policies.

I agree that they are not duplicates.  Sometimes people make mistakes.  In such cases, editing the question to make it clear how they differ and then if necessary requesting re-open votes following the standard procedure is a good way to handle it.
That said, in this specific case, the questions do have other issues.  So while the close-voters were wrong -- at the same time, the questions could also be improved.  Before complaining that the community is capricious or inconsistent, it would be better to address all the issues in your questions and make sure they are as good as they can be.
I think the way the questions are structured makes it easier for people to get confused.  I suggest that you revise the questions to improve them and reduce the likelihood of confusion, and work on improving how you ask questions in the future.  Of course, close-voters are still responsible to read carefully.  I don't mean to diminish that responsibility, but merely to identify what is in your power to address.
Both questions contain a long preamble, which is identical in both.  This makes it easy for someone skimming to see the similarities and mistakenly conclude they are duplicates.  Also, regardless of any confusion regarding duplicates, in general you should try to minimize the preamble to the absolute minimum needed for the specific question you are asking.  I don't think that's been done.  I see a long wall of text, and I think it's longer than it needs to be.
I would suggest that you improve your questions by focusing, in each question, solely on that one question, and optimize the preamble to list only what is needed.
You don't need to tell us that your exercise is to prove $A \le B \le C$ and your question is how to prove $A \le B$.  Just ask how to prove $A \le B$.  The rest of the exercise is irrelevant.
One of your questions appears to be a solution verification question: you list a proof, and you ask whether it is correct.  Such questions are not appropriate here.  Please review https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info, Best way of asking "check my proof" questions, and Don't close solution verification as dupe, instead remove questions with the tag of [solution-verification] appearing in search then reflect on those guidelines and consider whether there is a way to make your question suitable for the Stack Exchange format.
You claim that you have cited the portions of the proof that you are unsure about, but your actual question is "Can someone comment on whether I proved the LHS of the above Exercise correctly please?", which is too broad to be suitable here.  If you are unsure about what the meaning of $d_i$ is, don't show us your entire proof attempt and ask whether it is correct.  Instead, ask what $d_i$ means or what the definition of $d_i$ is.
Please try to make your question more concise.  I see an awful lot of text.  That makes it more time-consuming for people to understand and answer, and increases the chances of community votes that are incorrect.  In one question, you show a long attempted solution, then ask whether your proof is correct, then list some more statements (I'm not sure what the purpose of them is).  Instead, pick one fact that you want to know, and ask about that.  There's no need to show us a long attempted solution.  Try to ask a narrowly focused question that is easy for people to read without spending too much time.
I don't know what an "assumed exercise" is.  If you must use non-standard terms, please define them before first use, but I think it's better to just avoid those terms in the first place.  I don't understand why the "assumed exercise" is relevant.  I suspect it can be completely omitted.  If it is relevant, you should explain how it is relevant, rather than listing an "assumed exercise".  For instance, perhaps you could say that part of the motivation is you anticipate $A \le B$ might be a useful lemma for proving (broader result).
If you list an exercise, it is good practice to list where the exercise came from.  If it's from a textbook, list the textbook (name, authors) and the exercise number.  This helps others with a similar question to find your page via search.  I see that you've mentioned two textbooks, but you haven't listed which textbook the exercise came from, and what exercise number it is.  Also, we require you to credit the original source of all text originally written by others: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing
I suspect another issue might be that you are using the site in a slightly different way that Stack Exchange was designed for.  In fairness, the same could be said of many questions on Math.SE.  But the platform was originally designed and optimized for a specific purpose, and when we try to use it in other ways, the experience might not always be ideal.
Stack Exchange was created to make it easy for people to collaborate to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, structured in the form of questions and answers.  It wasn't intended as a helpdesk to help you specifically, but rather as a way that people could work together to document the answers to questions that many people might have.  As such, it is designed for focused questions that can be concisely explained and that will be relevant to many others.
How many people are going to have the same question about this exercise?  It's unclear.  Maybe.  If so, are they going to have exactly the same idea about a solution and want to know if it is correct?  I doubt it.  If you try to use the site to ask questions that aren't really part of the Stack Exchange mission, be prepared that you might find that your experience is variable, inconsistent, and sometimes unsatisfying.
I realize that it's challenging to achieve all of these ideals.  Also I realize that I have focused on the areas of potential improvement in your questions.  I think there is also a lot that you have done very well.  I am focusing on potential areas for improvement as I suspect those are ones that might (hopefully) help you get better results on this site.  I hope you won't be discouraged by my feedback.
